# Haskell chat server

Tags: haskell, telnet

I am trying to use the chat server code from wiki  
[Implement a chat server - HaskellWiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Implement_a_chat_server)
to connect to telenet with 
`$ telnet localhost 4242`
 as explained at the bottom of the site but I'm getting an error

```
 <interactive>:1:1: error:
     parse error on input `$' Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell
```

please let me know exactly what I'm doing wrong if you understand the error 
Thank You

Comment: Are you running the server in ghci?

Comment: i have no idea about haskell but.. maybe you are running command with '$' .. have you tried without '$' sign?

Comment: Are you entering `$ telnet localhost 4242` in a Haskell source file or GHCi? You’re supposed to run the program `telnet` *outside* of Haskell, in a terminal/command-line. `$` is a placeholder for the command prompt, so you’d just enter `telnet localhost 4242`. (This also assumes you have a telnet client installed on your machine and it’s available in your `PATH`.)

Comment: As a small correction, `telnet` should probably not be used (`nc` is probably better), since `telnet` is not just sending your text. It can also send Telnet control codes, and your server won't know how to handle them.

Answer (score 1):

The last line that tells you to test your code uses a common convention for shell scripts - the command is preceded with `$`, which is a default prompt character in a lot of places.

`telnet` is a system command which you should run directly from your OS shell, and not from the GHCi interpreter. And you're not supposed to include the `$` in the command itself.